# Как вывести топ N записей в таблице MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Например хочу вывести топ 10. Вот мой очень не оптимальный запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM question 
ORDER BY question_rating 
LIMIT 10
```

Как сделать это же, но по нормальному?

Comment: Почему вы считаете его не оптимальным. При наличии индекса по полю question_rating он должен отрабатывать быстро. а других нормальных способов все равно нет

Comment: ну разве что ```ORDER BY question_rating DESC```. Вам же, скорее всего нужны записи с самым высоким рейтингом, а не с самым низким?